# Bootstrap nav changes the font for a brief second on load momentarily shifting the buttons size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap nav (in WordPress using the Understrap starter theme) loses the font styling for a moment on page load, loading a default font for a split moment, and momentarily shifting the button size, what's happening here and how to fix it?

I've tried using `!important` with `font-family`, adding `.navbar .navbar-nav` before all the CSS selector names, and adding an `id` on the `body` tag, and prefacing the CSS selectors with that `id`. I'm still getting this momentary font shift.

Fonts are being loaded from Google Fonts.

```css
li a.nav-link, li a.nav-link:link, li a.nav-link:hover{
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px 16px 0 16px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

li a.nav-link:active, .active a.nav-link, li a.nav-link:focus{
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color:  #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid $000; 
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px 16px 0 16px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-primary" aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">
    
     <h2 id="main-nav-label" class="sr-only">
                Main Navigation</h2>
    
       <div class="container">

        <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav align-items-end ms-auto">
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-73 nav-item"><a title="Home" href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section1/" class="nav-link">Section 1</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section2/" class="nav-link">Section 2</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section3/" class="nav-link">Section 3</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-38 current_page_item active menu-item-77 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section4/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Section 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you using transitions or deferred loading of CSS?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I'm not sure, how would I figure that out? I'm using the Understrap theme.

Comment: Oh... Erm... Are you getting the requests loaded after the page is loaded? I am not sure how you can check but can you check the network tab? Like is the HTML loading first and then CSS is called or something?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it looks that way in the network tab, the page is the first entry, and everything else is after that. But all the wordpress sites I can see show the same thing in the network tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem in WordPress. Check out [this thread](https://wordpress.com/forums/topic/font-changes-as-page-loads/) related to the problem.

> On slower connections, we display text in the theme’s default font first. This way, people can start reading your content before the custom font loads, instead of waiting while looking at a blank page.

-- Said by WordPress staff member, ["fstat"](https://wordpress.com/forums/users/fstat/)

With that being said, let's look at ways we can work around this and make the google font the themes default font as a priority.

**Option 1:** You can import the google font using CSS and using the `@font-face` selector.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
}
```

**Option 2:** You can set `font-family` to the `body` and `*` universal selector.

This would entail putting the `<body>` tags around your HTML.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


li a.nav-link, li a.nav-link:link, li a.nav-link:hover{
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px 16px 0 16px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

li a.nav-link:active, .active a.nav-link, li a.nav-link:focus{
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    color:  #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid $000; 
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px 16px 0 16px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-primary" aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">
    
     <h2 id="main-nav-label" class="sr-only">
                Main Navigation</h2>
    
       <div class="container">

        <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav align-items-end ms-auto">
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-73 nav-item"><a title="Home" href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section1/" class="nav-link">Section 1</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section2/" class="nav-link">Section 2</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section3/" class="nav-link">Section 3</a></li>
                <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-38 current_page_item active menu-item-77 nav-item"><a title="" href="/section4/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Section 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, neither of those two fixes, or the fix in the link, resolved the issue :sad-face-emoji: